# I am going to ask about past tenses

Tags: grammar

I wanna know, if I describe to anyone about my past actions how can i say? Like- yesterday I didn’t go my college or I wasn’t go my college.. which is correct?

Comment: Welcome to the English Language Learners StackExchange, @NusratZaman. There's plenty of us here who like to answer questions to help people learn English, but it's really helpful to us if you can make your question as clear as possible, showing how you've tried to work it out for yourself. For example, have you looked at any references to help you work this out? Which option do you think is correct, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Use "didn't" in your example.

"Did" is the past tense of "do" and "was" is the past tense of "be."  Typically, when you use "be" + a verb, that verb should end in *-ing*.  For example:

> They were walking down the street.
>
> He isn't eating breakfast.
>
> I was going home.
>
> I wasn’t going to college.

Notice how all of these sentences (in the past tense) could be extended with a subordinate clause.  The sentences on their own seem like they're moving towards something else.  In your example you could say:

> Yesterday, I wasn't going to college until I remembered that I had a test.

Now using "do":

> They did walk down the street.
>
> He didn't eat breakfast.
>
> I did go home.
>
> I didn’t go to college.

Notice how none of the verbs end in *-ing*.  Also notice how in the sentences without negatives, the "do" could be left out entirely.  Finally, notice how it would be difficult to add a subordinate clause.  This includes your example:

> Yesterday, I didn't go to college.

In summary, use "be" when you want to continue your sentence to add more information or if an action extends over a period of time with verbs that end in *-ing*.  Use "do" when an object occurs at one point in time with verbs that don't end in *-ing*.  It can typically be left out, unless you're using "didn't" or "doesn't".